# Преобразование массива с отдельными задачами

Tags: массивы, преобразование, php, строки

Вот такой вопрос. Существует массив с n количеством ячеек, и к каждому элементу приписан ключ x.
Требуется преобразовать массив в строку с ключами, при этом первые два элемента удаляются из массива! Вот пример вывода массива:

```
<code>
'Image' => string 'http://media.digikey.com/Renders/Wurth%20Electronics%20Renders/0603(1608).jpg' (length=77)
  'Digi-Key Part Number' => string '732-4484-2-ND' (length=13)
  'Manufacturer Part Number' => string '74279266' (length=8)
  'Manufacturer' => string 'Wurth Electronics Inc' (length=21)
  'Description' => string 'FERR BEAD 1000 OHM WIDE BAND SMD' (length=32)
  'Quantity Available' => string '40000' (length=5)
  'Factory Stock' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Unit Price (USD)' => string '0.12750' (length=7)
  '@ qty' => string '0' (length=1)
  'Minimum Quantity' => string '4000' (length=4)
  'Packaging' => string 'Tape & Reel (TR)' (length=16)
  'Series' => string 'WE-CBF' (length=6)
  'Amplifier Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Applications' => string '' (length=0)
  'Capacitance' => string '' (length=0)
  'Connector Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Function' => string '' (length=0)
  'Logic Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Channels' => string '' (length=0)
  'Proto Board Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Resistance (Ohms)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Off State' => string '' (length=0)
  'Circuit' => string '' (length=0)
  'Direction' => string '' (length=0)
  'Inputs - Side 1/Side 2' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Circuits' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Elements' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Positions' => string '' (length=0)
  'Tolerance' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Gate Trigger (Vgt) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Input' => string '' (length=0)
  'Board Thickness' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Gate Trigger (Igt) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current Transfer Ratio (Min)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Bits per Element' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Inputs' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Outputs' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Rows' => string '' (length=0)
  'Power (Watts)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Isolation' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Rated' => string '' (length=0)
  'Common Mode Transient Immunity (Min)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Composition' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Output High, Low' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current Transfer Ratio (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'ESR (Equivalent Series Resistance)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Material' => string '' (length=0)
  'Pitch - Connector' => string '' (length=0)
  'Slew Rate' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - On State (Vtm) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Output' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Output 1' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - On State (It (AV)) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Gain Bandwidth Product' => string '' (length=0)
  'Independent Circuits' => string '' (length=0)
  'Input Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Pitch - Cable' => string '' (length=0)
  'Reset' => string '' (length=0)
  'Turn On / Turn Off Time (Typ)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Output 2' => string '' (length=0)
  '-3db Bandwidth' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - On State (It (RMS)) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Quiescent (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Delay Time - Propagation' => string '' (length=0)
  'Frequency - Clock' => string '' (length=0)
  'Length' => string '' (length=0)
  'Output Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Temperature Coefficient' => string '' (length=0)
  'Timing' => string '' (length=0)
  'Count Rate' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Hold (Ih) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Input Bias' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Output / Channel' => string '' (length=0)
  'Features' => string '' (length=0)
  'Color' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Off State (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Data Rate' => string '' (length=0)
  'Logic Level - Low' => string '' (length=0)
  'Trigger Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Input Offset' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Non Rep. Surge 50, 60Hz (Itsm)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Supply' => string '' (length=0)
  'Logic Level - High' => string '' (length=0)
  'Propagation Delay tpLH / tpHL (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Shielding' => string '' (length=0)
  'Size / Dimension' => string '0.063" L x 0.031" W (1.60mm x 0.80mm)' (length=37)
  'Voltage - Output (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Height' => string '' (length=0)
  'Height - Seated (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Max Propagation Delay @ V, Max CL' => string '' (length=0)
  'Rise / Fall Time (Typ)' => string '' (length=0)
  'SCR Type' => string '' (length=0)
  'Usage' => string '' (length=0)
  'Cable Termination' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - Quiescent' => string '' (length=0)
  'Lead Spacing' => string '' (length=0)
  'Number of Terminations' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Forward (Vf) (Typ)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Supply, Single/Dual ()' => string '' (length=0)
  'Contact Finish' => string '' (length=0)
  'Current - DC Forward (If) (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Input Capacitance' => string '' (length=0)
  'Manufacturer Size Code' => string '' (length=0)
  'Contact Finish Thickness' => string '' (length=0)
  'Vce Saturation (Max)' => string '' (length=0)
  'Voltage - Supply' => string '' (length=0)
  'Operating Temperature' => string '' (length=0)
  'Mounting Type' => string 'Surface Mount' (length=13)
  'Package / Case' => string '0603 (1608 Metric)' (length=18)
  'Supplier Device Package' => string '' (length=0)
</code>
```

Естественно, где пустые значения, данные элементы игнорируются, т.е. не выводятся.

Comment: Ни черта не понял, и не увидел примера массива. Дамп можно удалить, он ни о чем не говорит :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$stroka;
foreach($mass as $key => $value)
{
if($value != '')//тут мб и не такая проверка, проверять лень
{
$stroka .= $key.':'.$value.' ';
}
}
```

Что-то в этом духе